# Merge dataframes con diferente cantidad de filas en Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

Inicialmente tengo un dataframe, `df`, de la siguiente forma: (estos son datos de temperatura de los países)

```
|date      | Brasil | Colombia | Peru | Mexico|
------------------------------------------------
|2020-09-25|1       |4         |3      |2     |
|2020-09-26|3       |4         |3      |1     |
|2020-09-27|7       |5         |4      |3     |
|2020-09-28|0       |2         |4      |6     |
|2020-09-29|2       |4         |3      |4     |
|2020-09-30|1       |2         |3      |4     |
```

Y debo agregar las fechas que hacen falta hasta la actualidad, estas provienen de otros dataframe por país, que estan en un directorio de mi computador que lucen de la siguiente forma, por ejemplo para Colombia:

```
|datetime    |temp  |temp_max |
------------------------------
|2020-10-01  |5     |23       |   
|2020-10-02  |6     |22       |
|2020-10-01  |9     |23       |
|2020-10-03  |4     |25       |
|2020-10-04  |2     |4        |
|2020-10-05  |4     |12       |
|2020-10-06  |1     |11       |
```

el nombre de estos dataframe en el directorio es por ejemplo así `Colombia_20201006`. Yo cree el siguiente código que leyera los archivos y completara el dataframe `df`

```
columnas = numpy.array(df.columns)
columnas = numpy.delete(columnas,0)


path = "D:/Users/user/Documentos/"

lista_archivos = os.listdir(path)

for j in columnas: #Iternado por ciudades
    paises_archivos = []
    for i in lista_archivos:
        paises_activos.append(path+i) if i.startswith(f"{j}") else print("", end="")
    print(f"los archivos para el pais {j} son: {paises_archivos}")

    for g in paises_archivos:
        paises_concat = pd.read_csv(f"{g}")
        paises_concat = paises_concat[["datetime","temp"]]
        df_out = df.merge(paises_concat,how="outer", left_on="date", right_on="datetime")
        df_out = df_out.fillna("")
        df_out.loc[(df_out.date == "") & (df_out.datetime != ""), "date"] = df_out["datetime"] 
        df_out.loc[(df_out[f"{j}"] == "") & (df_out.temp != ""), f"{j}"] = df_out["temp"] 
        df_out = df_out.drop(["datetime", "temp"], axis=1)
```

El problema es que no necesariamente todos los archivos son iguales y puede que haya algunos que no tengan la misma fecha, por ejemplo puede (es una posibilidad, no una certeza) que haya algunos que, por ejemplo no tengan datos entre `2020-10-01`  y `2022-01-31`, y su dataframe luzca de la siguiente forma (Supongamos que este es el caso de Peru):

```
|datetime    |temp  |temp_max |
------------------------------
|2022-02-01  |5     |13       |   
|2022-02-02  |8     |12       |
|2022-02-03  |9     |13       |
|2022-02-04  |1     |15       |
|2022-02-05  |2     |14        |
|2022-02-06  |5     |14       |
|2022-02-07  |1     |15       |
```

Y lo que yo necesito es que llene los espacios que le faltan hasta 2022-02-01 con `NA` y quede algo más o menos así:

```
|date      | Brasil | Colombia | Peru | Mexico|
------------------------------------------------
|2020-09-25|1       |4         |3      |2     |
|2020-09-26|3       |4         |3      |1     |
|2020-09-27|7       |5         |4      |3     |
|2020-09-28|0       |2         |4      |6     |
|2020-09-29|2       |4         |3      |4     |
|2020-09-30|1       |2         |3      |4     |
|2020-10-01|1       |2         |NA     |4     |
|2020-10-02|1       |2         |NA     |4     |
|2020-10-03|1       |2         |NA     |4     |
|2020-10-04|1       |2         |NA     |4     |
|...       |...     |...       |...    |...   |
|2022-02-01|1       |5         |5      |6     |
|2022-02-02|1       |6         |8      |4     |
|2022-02-03|1       |9         |9      |8     |
|2022-02-04|1       |4         |1      |2     |
|2022-02-05|1       |2         |2      |1     |
|2022-02-06|1       |4         |5      |4     |
|2022-02-07|1       |1         |1      |3     |
```

Pero en este momento lo que el código está haciendo es dejar el dataframe de la siguiente forma:

```
|date      | Brasil | Colombia | Peru | Mexico|
------------------------------------------------
|2020-09-25|1       |4         |3      |2     |
|2020-09-26|3       |4         |3      |1     |
|2020-09-27|7       |5         |4      |3     |
|2020-09-28|0       |2         |4      |6     |
|2020-09-29|2       |4         |3      |4     |
|2020-09-30|1       |2         |3      |4     |
|2022-02-01|1       |5         |5      |6     |
|2022-02-02|1       |6         |8      |4     |
|2022-02-03|1       |9         |9      |8     |
|2022-02-04|1       |4         |1      |2     |
|2022-02-05|1       |2         |2      |1     |
|2022-02-06|1       |4         |5      |4     |
|2022-02-07|1       |1         |1      |3     |
|2020-10-01|1       |2         |       |4     |
|2020-10-02|1       |2         |       |4     |
|2020-10-03|1       |2         |       |4     |
|2020-10-04|1       |2         |       |4     |
|...       |...     |...       |...    |...   |
```

Realmente lo que yo necesito es que el código sea robusto ante la posibilidad de que no hayan datos para todas las fechas para todos los países. Pueden ayudarme?

Comment: Parece que en esta línea `df_out = df_out.fillna("")` le estás diciendo al programa que los datos vacíos los rellenes con un string vacío "", cámbiale el valor a `df_out.fillna("NA")`

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero hago eso y de igual manera sigue dejando la tabla de la forma en que no quiero. Mi deseo es que el código respete el orden cronológico, por así decirlo